# Maximum sequential speed for folder, defragment

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, defragment

How can I move folder at the beginning of the drive (partition) to achieve maximum sequential read speed in Windows? Can you recommend defragmentation tool that can do this ?

Comment: If you get an SSD you can have maximum speed across the whole drive without needing special defrag software. 500mb/s is common with SSD devices for read speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyDefrag is all you need. It uses custom scripts in order to defragment which you'll find at http://www.mydefrag.com/forum/index.php. Check the ones already made and create a custom script for yourself.